# Does Assassin's Creed Brotherhood "end" when I finish the main memory sequences?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

Assassin's Creed Revelations came out today and I'm still half a game behind!

I want to finish as much of the side stuff as possible, but I also want to get through the rest of the main story line quickly, so that I can play the new installment of the series without spoiling the ending of Brotherhood for myself.

Is it possible to go back and keep playing to complete guild challenges, side missions, etc. after the main memory sequences are completed or is it more like the original Fallout 3 where the game after the last quest in the main quest line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story does "end" but the gameplay does not.

You can still continue to do all of the side quests and replay old quests to try to get 100% (I'm on 99.5%, just can't 100% the damn tank mission).

Comment: Yeah, that mission really sucks.  It always got me at the end when you have to fight off two of 'em.

Comment: Finally got it myself a couple of days ago :) One more thing to note - after the end of the game there is at least one achivement you can no longer get if you missed it, because you can't explore Monteriggioni.